Threads don't see each other's data in process-specific keyring
I'm trying to write data in one thread and get it in another, like this:
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <keyutils.h>

int main()
{
    std::mutex m;
    
    auto f = [&]()
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(m);
        std::cout << "-----" << std::endl;

        key_serial_t ring = KEY_SPEC_PROCESS_KEYRING;
        const char* type = "user";
        const char* name = "test";
        
        long key = keyctl_search(ring, type, name, 0);
        std::cout << "get: " << key << std::endl;
        if (key == -1)
        {
            key = add_key(type, name, "1", 2, ring);
            std::cout << "set: " << key << std::endl;
            key = keyctl_search(ring, type, name, 0);
            std::cout << "get: " << key << std::endl;
        }
    };
    
    std::thread t1(f);
    std::thread t2(f);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}

On Ubuntu 24.04 I get output like this:
-----
get: -1
set: 979097589
get: 979097589
-----
get: -1
set: 534386259
get: 534386259

Looks like KEY_SPEC_PROCESS_KEYRING works exactly as KEY_SPEC_THREAD_KEYRING.
What am I doing wrong?
Updated code:
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <keyutils.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    std::mutex m;
    
    auto f = [&]()
    {
        auto s = "thread " + std::to_string(gettid()) + ": ";
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(m);

            key_serial_t ring = KEY_SPEC_PROCESS_KEYRING;
            const char* type = "user";
            const char* name = "test";
            
            long key = keyctl_search(ring, type, name, 0);
            cout << s << "get: " << key << endl;
            if (key == -1)
            {
                // perror("key");
                key = add_key(type, name, "1", 2, ring);
                cout << s << "set: " << key << endl;
                key = keyctl_search(ring, type, name, 0);
                cout << s << "get: " << key << endl;
            }
        }
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::lock_guard lock(m);
        cout << s << "end" << endl;
    };

    std::thread t1(f);
    std::thread t2(f);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    cout << "---" << endl;
    f();
    cout << "---" << endl;
    std::thread t3(f);
    std::thread t4(f);
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    return 0;
}

Output:
thread 39192: get: -1
thread 39192: set: 296360159
thread 39192: get: 296360159
thread 39193: get: -1
thread 39193: set: 186733216
thread 39193: get: 186733216
thread 39193: end
thread 39192: end
---
thread 39191: get: -1
thread 39191: set: 844445250
thread 39191: get: 844445250
thread 39191: end
---
thread 39195: get: 844445250
thread 39196: get: 844445250
thread 39196: end
thread 39195: end

So, the lifetime of threads doesn't matter.
Turns out, it is crucial to call first add_key on the main thread.
Still looks strange to me. Is it a bug in kernel or what?

Removed the C tag, since C and C++ are different languages and the posted code is C++.

Does the code work if you just do f(); f(); no threads ?

add perror("user key"); to part which handles error to see what actually happen. Maybe there is other type of error then just "not found".

@Richard Critten
It woks. Subsequent keyctl_search calls in same thread return same value.

@Marek R
user key: Required key not available
errno: ENOKEY

It looks like a data race. In the manual process-keyring(7):

The process keyring is destroyed when the last thread that refers to it terminates.

A second thread does not have a chance to refer a keyring before a first thread termination. You may delay thread exits or synchronize threads at end.

I wouldn't call it a race, it's not a concurrent access to the same data. And there is a third thread, main. But I checked this possibility and updated the question.
